# OSX deprecated bluetooth functions

Tags: macos, bluetooth, iobluetooth

I am following the "Bluetooth Device Access Guide" in the Mac Developer library, regarding how to implement a Mac RFCOMM server. Part way through the guide on how to add a service definition to the SDP database there is a code listing that uses a deprecated function:

```
// Now that we have an IOBluetoothSDPServiceRecord object,
// we no longer need the IOBluetoothSDPServiceRecordRef.
IOBluetoothObjectRelease( serviceRecordRef );
```

[Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/Conceptual/Bluetooth/BT_Develop_BT_Apps/BT_Develop_BT_Apps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000997-CH216-TP9)

When googling this function I found several open-source projects that still use the function as well. I also found some change logs saying that this function has been removed, and I found some header documentation stating the following:

```
The ref counting scheme allows the IOBluetoothObjectRefs to be freed 
when they are no longer used. When the ref count reaches zero, 
the target object will be freed.

***      DEPRECATED IN BLUETOOTH 2.2 (Mac OS X 10.6) ***      
You should transition your code to Objective-C equivalents. ***      
This API may be removed any time in the future.
```

Based on this, my questions are:

- Why is the Mac documentation using a deprecated function?
- What is the Objective-C equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the:

```
IOBluetoothAddServiceDict
```

function has also been deprecated (but is still available). Instead, I should be using

```
+[IOBluetoothSDPServiceRecord publishedServiceRecordWithDictionary:]
```

which doesn't seem to require the use of the release function.

Comment: Just ran into the same thing, any chance you could post your updated code?

Comment: @AdamMcCormick Here's what my code looks like. https://gist.github.com/ui-philip/78897d6f304aa9411bcb. Keep in mind that you need a BluetoothService.plist file as well.

Comment: Thanks, that is so much cleaner than the official documentation. I'd love to see your plist as well if you'd be willing to share.

Comment: @pbergqvist do you still have the gist you posted? I'm trying to learn how to make a bluetooth service myself currently and am finding the official apple docs lacking

Comment: @Scott My github username has changed. Try this instead: https://gist.github.com/pqvst/78897d6f304aa9411bcb